# Potential misbehavior of the "$" qualifier in the .Net Regular Expression processing

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-core, console-application

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) says:

**Qualifier**: `$`

**Description**: The match must occur at the end of the string or before `\n` at the end of the line or string.

**Pattern example**: `-\d{3}$`

**Text match example**: `-333` in `-901-333`

I expected that the qualifier `$` will match end-of-string when we use `RegexOptions.Singleline` and match end-of-line when we use `RegexOptions.Multiline` as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"_
abc
123
do-re-me";
            var pat = @"\w+$";
            var re = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            var ms = re.Matches(text);
            var i = 0;
            foreach (Match m in ms)
                Console.WriteLine($"{i++}.  {m}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code (`RegexOptions.Multiline`) resulted in:

```
0.  me
```

I used both .Net framework 4.7.1 and .Net Core 2.0 with a Console App and got the same result.

I expected the result to be:

```
0.  _
1.  abc
2.  123
3.  me
```

Note that the `^` qualifier worked as expected.  Matched the beginning of the line when using `RegexOptions.Multiline` and the beginning of the string when using `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Can anyone explain the behavior of the `$` qualifier?

Answer (score 3):

I predict you're writing this source code on a Windows machine... where the line endings - embedded in your verbatim string literal - are "\r\n", not "\n".

You're currently looking for a word character followed by a "\n" - which it won't find, because there's a "\r" in the way.

If you remove the "\r" characters first, it works as you expect it to:

```
text = text.Replace("\r", "");
```

Alternatively, just change the format of your source code to use "\n" instead of "\r\n" as the line ending. Or as a third option, don't use a verbatim string literal:

```
string text = "_\nabc\n123\ndo-re-me";
```

Any of these options will give you the result you expect.

This is one of the issues with verbatim string literals, unfortunately. It's particularly problematic if you're working with a source control system which automatically translates between formats when cloning :(

Answer (score 3):

The other answer shed some light on this issue but you don't need to remove carriage returns from your string. It's cleared in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#End). You'd want to use **`\r?$`** instead of `$` alone:

> If you use `$` with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, the match can
>   also occur at the end of a line. Note that `$` matches `\n` but does not
>   match `\r\n` (the combination of carriage return and newline characters,
>   or CR/LF). To match the CR/LF character combination, include **`\r?$`** in
>   the regular expression pattern.